# Cannot access variables within a widget

Tags: plugins, php, functions, widgets, sidebar

I'm currently learning PHP and Wordpress development from a Java background at the moment. How do I access variables in `public function Example_Widget()` from `public function widget( $args, $instance )`? When I use `var_dump($Example_Widget->$ranNum);` it shows up as null. Which, of course, not true. This is all new to me.

```
<?php
        add_action( 'widgets_init', 'example_load_widgets' );

        function example_load_widgets() {
            register_widget( 'Example_Widget' );
        }

        class Example_Widget extends WP_Widget {

        function __construct() {
                parent::__construct(
                    'Random_Profile_Widget', // Base ID
                    'Random Profiles', // Name
                    array( 'description' => __( 'Drag this widget to any sidebar to display random profiles.', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
                );
            }

            public function Example_Widget() {

                            $args = array(
                                'posts_per_page'   => 99,
                                'offset'           => 0,
                                'category'         => '',
                                'category_name'    => '',
                                'orderby'          => 'post_date',
                                'order'            => 'DESC',
                                'include'          => '',
                                'exclude'          => '',
                                'meta_key'         => '',
                                'meta_value'       => '',
                                'post_type'        => 'resume',
                                'post_mime_type'   => '',
                                'post_parent'      => '',
                                'post_status'      => 'publish',
                                'suppress_filters' => true 
                            );
                            $resumes = get_posts($args);            
                            $ranNum = rand ( 0 , sizeof($resumes) - 1 );
                            $resume = $resumes[$ranNum];                                    
            }
        public function widget( $args, $instance ) { ?>
                    <p><?php var_dump($Example_Widget->$ranNum); ?></p> 
        <?php }
    }

    /* Stop Adding Functions Below this Line */
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a pure PHP than WordPress.

1. You are implicitly creating `$ranNum` as local variable in function scope.
2. `$Example_Widget` won't access widget instance in PHP.

What you should be using is `$this->ranNum`, for reading and writing. That will create object's property implicitly, but you likely should declare it explicitly in your class definition (see PHP docs on [properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)).